# How to Recover files from a CDROM?

Tags: linux, fedora, testdisk

i have a mini cdrom, there are bluetooth drivers on it.

i wanted to copy the files from the cdrom, but it seems...one file [?] is corrupted

Can anyone help me? How could i recover the files from my CD? [using Fedora 14]

Can anyone post a link to a page/howto?
Thank you:\

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas

- Clean the CD - if necessary [CD Cleaning](http://www.howtocleanthings.com/how-to-clean-a-cd.htm)
- If still no success copy the disc to disc/image and try to read it out from the copy

(search the internet for the drivers/files)